# CSS background image blur

Tags: css, filter, blur

I have this example : http://jsfiddle.net/ruchan/8efhk9f5/

I want to make the background(only) of the blocks blurred.
using 
`filter: blur(5px);` makes whole content around it blurred.

Tried using it inside `:before`but still doesn't works

How do i only blur the background, and leave the content un-blurred.

Answer (score 2):

There is a proposed CSS mechanism to do this in the [draft version of the filters spec](http://dev.w3.org/fxtf/filters/#FilterCSSImageValue), but it's not implemented in any browsers yet (that I'm aware of) (**edit: implemented in WebKit nightlies now, and supposedly is in Mobile Safari iOS 9**). For future readers of this answer, this **may** be a viable solution.

It looks like this:

```
.thing {
  background-image: filter(url('myimage.png'), blur(10px));
}
```

So, basically it's a functional notation that lets you apply a filter to an image as you load it.
Again, **this is not supported anywhere as of right now**.

The [example from CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/frosting-glass-css-filters/) mentioned in another answer uses a pseudo-element to basically create a duplicate of an element using the same background, and then blurs that with a filter. That should work as a realistic solution today (at least for browsers that support CSS filters - don't forget the `-webkit-` prefix as well as the unprefixed version!), otherwise you'll have to fall back to a manually created blurred image.

Comment: I tried from the **frosting glass**, cannot convert it to my version though. http://jsfiddle.net/ruchan/8efhk9f5/9/

Comment: You need to give the pseudo-element some dimensions: add `width: 100%; height: 100%;` to the `.glass:before` rule. Link: http://jsfiddle.net/mhLwqgnb/